# Modify Navigation Fragment after Async Call

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have an Aync task

`public class XmlNetwork extends AsyncTask< String, Void, List<PEMenuItem>`

which essentially loads up an xml file into some objects that I want to use to change my navigation drawer menu items. it has an override function

`protected void onPostExecute(List<PEMenuItem> result)`

and so result is now a list of 3 objects i loaded from the xml.

at this point, i would like to make a call within my class

`public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment`

to build out the menu, add the onclicklisteners, etc.

i've previously learned how to add some callbacks, to call from the fragment out to my main activity, but how would i go about doing the inverse, calling from my Async class out to the fragment? i want to send the list along with it, something along the lines of

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<PEMenuItem> result) {
        NavigationDrawerFragment fragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getFragment().modifyMenu(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The menu items in your NavigationDrawerFragment are usually just items in a ListView. As such, they are backed by an Adapter. Set your new items as that adapter's content and call notifyOnDatasetChanged on the adapter. This will cause the list to re-obtain the items from that adapter. For example you could use something like this as an adapter to your menu list (simplified):

```
public class MenuItemsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<String> menuItems;

    public MenuItemsAdapter(Context context) {       
        this.context = context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        //Empty for now
        menuItems = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void setNewMenuItems(List<String> newMenuItems) {
        this.menuItems = newMenuItems;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return menuItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int i) {
        return menuItems.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if(view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_menu_item_layout, viewGroup, false);
        }

        TextView menuItemText = view.findViewByIt(R.id.your_menu_item_text);
        menuItemText = menuItems.get(position);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, i think i get what you're saying as far as updating with the new content, but i guess my problem is still reaching across the classes. the `private ListView mDrawerListView;` is part of `NavigationDrawerFragment` class, so how would I modify those values from the `onPostExecute` call in my `XmlNetwork` class?

Comment: i have seperated out the Adapter into it's own class, and it's working within the fragment, I am able to send it context and get it to display the list properly. my problem at this point is basically the same as above, i can't create the `MenuItemsAdapter` object in my `AsyncTask` object so that i can assign values/call `notifyOnDatasetChanged` in the `onPostExecute` because i can't send it (or can't figure out how to) send it the proper context.